# Segmentation fault with files in C

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault

i start coding in C for studies but we don't have any courses or lessons on it. 
I have a segmentation fault 11 with a simple program and i don't know why. I need to use files btw:
thx for the help ^^

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int i;

typedef struct Passager{
    char nom[20];
    char prenom[20];
    int age;
    int num_siege;
} Passager;
Passager liste_passagers[30]; //30 = nombre de passagers

int main()
{
    FILE* fichier = NULL;
    fichier = fopen("/Users/Patoch/Desktop/Patoch /UNI/Informatique/info sem 2/Structure de données/Labo/TP3/Passager2.txt", "r");

    if (fichier == NULL)
    { //test de la bonne ouverture du fichiers
        printf("Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier Passagers.docx");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }   

    for (i=0; i<(sizeof(liste_passagers)/sizeof(liste_passagers[0])); i++)
    {
        fscanf(fichier, "%s %s %d %d", liste_passagers[i].nom, liste_passagers[i].prenom, &liste_passagers[i].age, &liste_passagers[i].num_siege);
        printf("nom : %s \n", liste_passagers[i].nom);

    }

    fclose(fichier); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to have a fail-to-open case, you probably shouldn't march on into code that uses the very NULL `FILE*` you just identified. The `fclose`, and every other filestream api, that is invoked on that NULL is going to exhibit undefined behavior (and if you're lucky, crash the program in revolt). Just saying. That `fclose(fichier);` should be `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` (or just `return EXIT_FAILURE;`).

Comment: `sizeof(liste_passagers)` does not give you the number of elements. You need `sizeof(liste_passagers) / sizeof(liste_passagers[0])`. Better would be to generalise the hard-coded `30` in the array definition.

Comment: and don't really understand how to use the sizeof. Should i alway do this / sizeof(...[0])) ?

Comment: Always check the return value from `fscanf` which here should be `4`, this would have trapped the data overrun too. You are blindly trying to fill an array beyond its bounds with data that does not exist. Moreover start the indexing loop from `i = 0`

Comment: No you can't always do that. When an array is a function parameter that won't work: you'll need to pass the number of elements as another parameter.

Comment: So now that i used the exit failure instead of the fclose, it works. But i still can't read the file. Why ?

Comment: Try using the full path name; the environment from which you are running the program may not have the right "current working directory".

Comment: My file is exactly in the same directory as my code

Comment: That's not what I said. The IDE, or the file viewer (e.g. Windows Explorer) may know where the program is, but the program may not know where the data file is.

Comment: What do you mean so ? do you mean the full path of my file ?

Comment: ok, it works thx ^^
But now this doesn't read it correctly xD i mean i only have char and int in it but it print some wierd stuff

Comment: If you've changed the code according to the comments here, please update your question with those changes.

Comment: i needed an .txt and not docx thx for the help

Comment: As a final comment, another possibility than using the size divide trick is to simply have `#define MaxPassengers 30` and then use that both in the array declaration and in the for-loop condition. Unifies it quite nicely and is much less error prone.

Answer (score 0):

Should be `nom` and `prenom` definition space is too small, try to let the fscanf allocate space when it want it.

like as:

```
fscanf(fp, "%ms", &ptr);
```

modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int i;

typedef struct Passager {
    char *nom;
    char *prenom;
    int age;
    int num_siege;
} Passager;
Passager liste_passagers[30]; //30 = nombre de passagers

int main()
{
    FILE *fichier = NULL;
    fichier = fopen("Passager2.txt", "r");

    if (fichier == NULL) {
        //test de la bonne ouverture du fichiers
        printf("Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier Passagers.docx");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(liste_passagers) / sizeof(liste_passagers[0])); i++) {
        fscanf(fichier, "%ms %ms %d %d",
               &liste_passagers[i].nom, &liste_passagers[i].prenom,
               &liste_passagers[i].age, &liste_passagers[i].num_siege);
        printf("nom : %s \n", liste_passagers[i].nom);
        free(liste_passagers[i].nom);
        free(liste_passagers[i].prenom);
    }

    fclose(fichier);
    return 0;
}
```